# How to not send Vacation Responder if email contains attachment

Tags: gmail

Please note, I am *not* trying to send an attachment with the vacation responder.

I am trying to set up an indefinite vacation responder in Gmail that informs anybody emailing the address that it is no longer active. *However*, there is a script set up that saves any attachments to a Google Drive folder. I don't want the email to auto-reply to these people, since they know about this functionality and are not expecting a response.

So basically, is there any way (even using a 3rd party app) that I can set up an auto-response email to be sent to everyone, excluding those who attach files in the original message.

Answer (score 1):

Not by using the vacation auto-responder, but you probably could do something with filters and Canned Responses.

First, you'll need to set up the Canned Response.

Next, create a filter that looks for `-has:attachment`. That should fire on any message that does *not* have an attachment. Set the action of the filter to respond with your canned response.

That should be all you need to do.